# .NET: GDI+ scaling - cache scaled bitmaps?

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

I am working on an application which displays a background image with a number of glyphs/graphic objects scattered on top of the background. Panning and zooming is implemented.

Internal representation of the displayed graphics has precise coordinates and sizes in millimeters - the graphic needs to reflect the real world drawings.
So far I am using the GDI+ transformation matrix to operate in my coordinate system and have the framework do calculations and drawing. It's very convenient indeed.

```
private Matrix SetupGraphicTransformation()
{
    Matrix mx = new Matrix();
    mx.Scale(_zoom, _zoom);
    mx.Translate(this.AutoScrollPosition.X / Project.RasterizedImage.HorizontalResolution, this.AutoScrollPosition.Y / Project.RasterizedImage.VerticalResolution, MatrixOrder.Append);
    return mx;
}
```

However, I am facing a performance problem caused by my OnPaint event which needs to output background and objects. Background is the biggest issue. Is is painted like this:

```
// ...
// in OnPaint
e.Graphics.Transform = SetupGraphicTransformation();
e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = _interpolationMode;

this.DrawMainImage(e.Graphics);
this.DrawTagObjects(e.Graphics);
// ...


private void DrawMainImage(Graphics graphics)
{
    graphics.DrawImage(Project.RasterizedImage.Image,
        0, 0, Project.RasterizedImage.ActualSize.Width, Project.RasterizedImage.ActualSize.Height);
    // ActualSize is in mm
}
```

My first idea was to go away from the scaling within the transformation, just resize the bitmap when user zooms to a certain zoom level and output that pre-scaled bitmap. But then of course I lose the scaling of other objects' coordinates and would need to perform all the calculations.

As I understand this, it is GDI+ which decides to scale the bitmap after looking at its original size and the size of the viewport and performing all the calculations. And it always does scale because I am always going from the original image. 
How would you go about avoiding the scaling when it isn't needed?

Comment: Sure, rescaling large bitmaps is pretty expensive and will noticeably slow down your UI when you do it when you paint.  Burning several hundred msec is not uncommon, you can see that.  So don't do that.  Rescale just once, whenever it *needs* to be done.  And use the 32bppPArgb pixel format, it is 10 times faster than the other ones.

Comment: Well, yes, that's the general idea. However (maybe I didn't explain it clear enough) I would like to resize the bitmap, store it in a variable and output the resized version - i.e. 1-to-1, without transformations. And the rest of the drawing should then be done _with transformation_ as before.
Hm, maybe I will try just that - first output background, _then_ apply the new matrix and do the rest of the drawing? Somehow I never thought about this till now.